# Spring: Why do I need to add a javax.el-api dependency when loading the application context in a unit test?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, hibernate-validator, gretty

I created a simple Spring 5 application with spring-mvc. In one of my model objects I use bean validation (hibernate-validator). I added the following configuration to make it all work:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "nl.myprod.springcrud")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

When launching my full application with Gretty, everything works as expected. But when I run the following test....

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebConfig.class})
public class tmpTest {

    @Test
    public void tmp () {

    }

}
```

... it gives me the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodValidationPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [nl/myprod/springcrud/config/AppConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:129)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:275)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.buildExpressionFactory(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.<init>(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultMessageInterpolator(ConfigurationImpl.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultMessageInterpolatorConfiguredWithClassLoader(ConfigurationImpl.java:650)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getMessageInterpolator(ConfigurationImpl.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:364)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:103)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.<init>(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor.createMethodValidationAdvice(MethodValidationPostProcessor.java:125)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor.afterPropertiesSet(MethodValidationPostProcessor.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELManager
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.buildExpressionFactory(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:108)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.ELManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 53 more
```

Now I know that I can fix it by adding the following dependency to my build.gradle:

`compile group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.el', version: '3.0.0'`

And I can also fix this by not loading my ApplicationContext (comment out *@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebConfig.class})* in the test).

But I don't see why my code works fine when run with Gretty, but fails configuration in the tests. Can anyone explain to me why this is?

PS: This is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.gretty' version '2.3.1'
}

gretty {
    httpPort=8081
}

group 'nl.myprod'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '5.1.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.7'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '5.1.4.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '1.10.19'
    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-all', version: '1.3'

    compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate.validator', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.0.13.Final'
}
```

Comment: When using it only for model validation you don't need the `MethodValidationPostProcessor`... That is only for enabling `@Validated` on non `@Controller` beans like like `@Service`. None the less, `javax.validation` depends on `javax.el` because the messages can be expressions which need to be parsed/resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like when you start Gretty at least in Tomcat mode it includes some implementation of those `EL` classes.

The following files have `EL` dependencies:

- https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/blob/master/libs/gretty-runner-tomcat8/build.gradle: 
  `compile "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:$tomcat8_version"`
- https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/blob/master/libs/gretty-runner-tomcat7/build.gradle: `compile "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:$tomcat7_version"`

Comment: Aaah I see... That makes sense I guess. Thanks!